# How to fix a slightly raised stair nosing board

Tags: hardwood-floor, stairs

(See photo below).

I have hardwood flooring that goes into stairs.  The horizontal wooden slat right before the stairs is very slightly raised, by maybe an 1/8 of an inch, maybe even 1/16th.  It's not a major problem, but I'm worried it's a tripping hazard which could end horribly wrong if you trip down the whole flight of stairs.

Is there a way I can make the two hardwood slats smooth with each other?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it move down when pressure is applied, like stepping on it? If so, it just needs a nail or nails in the right place to keep it down. Need more info to say where. The picture does not show where the problem area is. Is it the piece at the edge of the stairs, or is it one of the pieces of flooring perpendicular to it?

Comment: It’s the horizontal piece in the picture. In some of those areas the vertical hardwood flooring connects with it at a 1/16 of an inch lower than the horizontal slab. 

It doesn’t move down on pressure. I can try to post another photo from a lower angle

Comment: I added another photo from a lower angle to hopefully show the issue. I don't think it's that extreme, but the fact that this is right at the top of the stairs scares me a little about elderly family going downstairs and potentially tripping on it.

Comment: Please check it more closely. When flooring is installed and sanded all surfaces are uniform before the finish is applied. It is the nature of the work. If it was a prefinished floor, it would be a different matter. Anyways, the only way i seen what you have there is something has started to move, even just a little. OR... is the upper floor a prefinished floor???? Then that will be a different matter a well.

Comment: Not part of the question, but it looks like the nosing is not in line with the rest of the steps. THAT is more of a trip hazard than anything else.

Comment: @Jack: I actually think my question is about the nosing. I’m new to this diy stuff so I’m not fully clear on the terminology yet, but what I am referring to is when someone is walking down the stairs, that very first (top) nosing is what causes a slight trip hazard, which is what I want to fix if possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105069/discussion-between-jack-and-david).

Comment: I realize that is what you were referring to after the latest picture

Comment: i had two uneven floor surfaces like that that i fixed by drilling small holes in the lower surface, injecting gorilla glue into the hole, then hot-gluing the hole shut. One i had to drill a screw into partly to provide a handle to lift it slightly  before glue injection. The glue expands and lifts up the lower plank slightly before it turns rock hard. Then, all i had to do was pull out the hot glue, fill with wood putty, sand/stain/etc.

Comment: It's common for those nosings to be heavier than the rest of the floor. They carry a huge amount of torque. I would consider transitioning the edge with a bevel and leave it alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the top step is slightly higher than the hardwood flooring it shouldn't be much of a problem to pull it up and plane down the underside to the thickness you're seeking. You just don't want to overdo it. Be patient in removing the stair slat to prevent splitting.
**EDIT**
If the stair is mortised into the stringer the only realistic solution is to carefully use a sanding block to bevel the back edge of the step to reduce the risk. If you can keep the bevel area narrow and not impact the flooring you might be able to apply a matching stain and seal to the bevel that will be acceptable visually.

Comment: how do I go about pulling out the top step?

Comment: If the nosing is a "housed" nosing, as in mortised into the stringers, that will be very difficult to do. If the nosing is part of an older set of stairs and the skirt boards are cut over the treads and nosing, that will also be very difficult to do. It will require cutting it out and replacing it with new, sorry to say.

Comment: @David - Are the stairs mortised in to the stringers or are the treads simply flush with the stringers?

Comment: @HoneyDo: truthfully I have no idea how to answer that. Is there a way to know?

Comment: Visual inspection. If the white trim along the sides is overlapping the tread then you should probably go to plan B. I've seen it both ways.

Comment: Plan B: If you decide to bevel the back edge of the step with a sanding block I would first put something down over the front edge of the flooring to protect it from damage. A mastic trowel or something similar would probably do it. Hold it in place at an angle - handle side down. Use it as a guide to hold the sanding block at an angle and smooth down the back edge of the tread until you get it where you want it. There will still be a rise in the step but you'll significantly reduce the tripping risk.

Comment: @honeydo alright, I’ll try to go with your plan B! Many thanks to you and everybody in this thread, learned a lot about stairs and how they’re built in this process.

Answer (score 1):

If that is real wood (and not laminate), you could sand it down.  I would tape off the remaining to avoid accidentally sanding the other planks. However you must have the correct stain color to refinish it.

Removing it, as suggested above, is best. But if you can't remove it due to some constraint, sanding is another option.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen stairs that could easily be disassembled in-situ. The treads are usually morticed into the stringers, then glued and wedged into place, along with the risers with which they interlock, starting at the top and ending at the bottom, so disassembly would be in the opposite order requiring access to bottom riser from below.(assembly is done in the joinery factory then the assembled stairs are connected to the framing).

The best fix is probably to raise the hardwood flooring and pack under it with building paper (etc) until it is level, while the easiest is to plane or sand the top step down until it is level with the floor and then re-finish it.

It may be possible to access the underside of the floor and pry the boards up a little and then hammer wedges in to raise the floor.